# What is the equivelent to Java's Integer.reverseBytes() in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an application that reads in some strings in [Q Number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29).

The java implementation converts a string like this:

```java
int i = Integer.parseInt("00801600", 16);
System.out.println("Number from Integer.parseInt = " + i); // i=8394240
float j = Integer.reverseBytes(i);
System.out.println("After Integer.reverseBytes = " + j); // j=1474560.0
float k = j / 65536; //TWO_POWER_OF_16 = 65536
System.out.println("After Q division = " + k); // k=22.5
```

I've played with a lot of combinations of swift functions, and this is (hopefully) pretty close:

```swift
let i: Int = Int("00801600", radix: 16) ?? 0
let istr = "Number from Int = \(i)"
let j: Double = Double(i.byteSwapped)
let jstr = "After byte swapping = \(j)"
let k: Double = Double(j) / 65536.0
let kstr = "After Q division = \(k)"
```

Obviously, `Int.byteSwapped` isn't what I'm looking for. In my example above, `j` is where it all goes off the rails. The java code produces `1474560.0`, whereas my swift is `6333186975989760.0`.

Comment: hold up, you can assign an `int` (the result of [`Integer.reverseBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes(int)) to a `float` without a cast? Oh ffs.

Comment: Implicit type conversions are normal in C derivatives. Swift is the exception in this regard.

Comment: @robmayoff I thought that was only for lossless conversions. It's been a while haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Java `int` is always 32 bits, so `Integer.reverseBytes` turns 0x00801600 into 0x00168000.

A Swift `Int` is 32 bits on 32-bit platforms and 64 bits on 64-bit platforms (which is most current platforms). So on a 32-bit platform, `i.byteSwapped` turns 0x00801600 into 0x00168000, but on a 64-bit platform, `i.byteSwapped` turns 0x0000000000801600 into 0x0016800000000000.

If you want 32 bits, be explicit:

```
  1> let i = Int32("00801600", radix: 16)!
i: Int32 = 8394240
  2> let j = Double(i.byteSwapped)
j: Double = 1474560
  3> let k = j / 65536
k: Double = 22.5
  4>
```

Comment: I just looked up Q encoding on wikipedia, and from what I read I expected for there to somewhere be a parameter that dictates how much of the bits of `i` are the numerator, and how many are the denominator. Is that implicitly encoded in the devision by `65536`, which is `2^16`?

Comment: I guess the input is Q16, but we don't need to know that to answer the question, since the question is essentially “How do I make this Swift program give the same answer as this Java program?”

Comment: Yes, the strings I'm working with are Q16. Changing to `Int32` totally solves it. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @livingtech You have a pretty big code smell going on there. Your numbers are `Q16`, but your code doesn't mention that anywhere at all. I had to reverse engineer it to figure that out. This is *desperately* calling out to be its own data type.

Comment: My impression was that the code in the question is toy code to demonstrate the problem. We don't know what livingtech's production code looks like, and it's not relevant to his question.

Answer (score -1):

You say that you're trying to implement Q encoded numbers, but the Java code you've shown doesn't really do that. It hard-codes the case of Q16 (by virtue of dividing by `65536`, which is 2^16), but frankly, I'm not even sure how it's intended to work, but it doesn't.

`0x00801600` when Q encoded with a numerator of size 16, represents `0x0080 / 0x1600`, which is `128 / 5632`, which is equal to ~0.0227. Even if you imagine that your input is swapped, `5632 / 128` is `44`, not `22.5`. So I don't see any interpretation under which this math works out.

To implement this in Swift (and in Java, for that matter), I would make a new `QEncoded` data type, that stores an integer and a number of bits that count towards the numerator (the number of bits that count for the denominator can be inferred as the formed minus the latter).

This approach is the most flexible, but it isn't particularly efficient (since it wastes one `Int` for the `numeratorBitWidth` for every instance). If you have so many of these that memory usage is a concern, you can use a more protocol oriented approach, which I detail in a [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56224399/3141234).

```
// A QEncoded binary number of the form Qm.n https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29
struct QEncoded<I: BinaryInteger> {
    var i: I
    var numeratorBitWidth: Int // "m"   
    var denominatorBitWidth: Int { return i.bitWidth - numeratorBitWidth } // "n"

    var numerator: I {
        return i >> denominatorBitWidth
    }

    var denominator: I {
        if denominatorBitWidth == 0 { return 1 }
        let denominatorMask: I = (1 << I(numeratorBitWidth)) - 1
        return i & denominatorMask
    }

    var ratio: Double { return Double(numerator) / Double(denominator) }

    var qFormatDescription: String {
        let (m, n) = (self.numeratorBitWidth, self.denominatorBitWidth)
        return (n == 0) ?  "Q\(m)" : "Q\(m).\(n)"
    }

    init(bitPattern: I, numeratorBitWidth: Int, denominatorBitWidth: Int) {
        assert(numeratorBitWidth + denominatorBitWidth == bitPattern.bitWidth, """
        The number of bits in the numerator (\(numeratorBitWidth)) and denominator (\(denominatorBitWidth)) \
        must sum to the total number of bits in the integer \(bitPattern.bitWidth)
        """)

        self.i = bitPattern
        self.numeratorBitWidth = numeratorBitWidth
    }

//  Might be useful to implement something like this:
//  init(numerator: I, numeratorBits: Int, denominator: I, denominatorBits: Int) {
//      
//  }
}
```

Here's a little demo:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var binaryDescription: String {
        var binaryString = ""
        var internalNumber = self
        var counter = 0

        for _ in (1...self.bitWidth) {
            binaryString.insert(contentsOf: "\(internalNumber & 1)", at: binaryString.startIndex)
            internalNumber >>= 1
            counter += 1
            if counter % 4 == 0 {
                binaryString.insert(contentsOf: " ", at: binaryString.startIndex)
            }
        }

        return binaryString
    }
}

extension QEncoded {
    func test() {
        print("\(self.i.binaryDescription) with \(qFormatDescription) encoding is: \(numerator.binaryDescription) (numerator: \(numerator)) / \(denominator.binaryDescription) (denominator: \(denominator)) = \(ratio)")
    }
}

//                     ↙︎ This common "0_" prefix does nothing, it's just necessary because "0b_..." isn't a valid form
//                        The rest of the `_` denote the seperation between the numerator and denominator, strictly for human understanding only (it has no impact on the code's behaviour)
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0__00111111 as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 0, denominatorBitWidth: 8).test()
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0_0_0111111 as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 1, denominatorBitWidth: 7).test()
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0_00_111111 as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 2, denominatorBitWidth: 6).test()
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0_001_11111 as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 3, denominatorBitWidth: 5).test()
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0_0011_1111 as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 4, denominatorBitWidth: 4).test()
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0_00111_111 as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 5, denominatorBitWidth: 3).test()
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0_001111_11 as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 6, denominatorBitWidth: 2).test()
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0_0011111_1 as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 7, denominatorBitWidth: 1).test()
QEncoded(bitPattern: 0b0_00111111_ as UInt8, numeratorBitWidth: 8, denominatorBitWidth: 0).test()
```

Which prints:

```
0011 1111 with Q0.8 encoding is:  0000 0000 (numerator: 0) /  0000 0000 (denominator: 0) = -nan
 0011 1111 with Q1.7 encoding is:  0000 0000 (numerator: 0) /  0000 0001 (denominator: 1) = 0.0
 0011 1111 with Q2.6 encoding is:  0000 0000 (numerator: 0) /  0000 0011 (denominator: 3) = 0.0
 0011 1111 with Q3.5 encoding is:  0000 0001 (numerator: 1) /  0000 0111 (denominator: 7) = 0.14285714285714285
 0011 1111 with Q4.4 encoding is:  0000 0011 (numerator: 3) /  0000 1111 (denominator: 15) = 0.2
 0011 1111 with Q5.3 encoding is:  0000 0111 (numerator: 7) /  0001 1111 (denominator: 31) = 0.22580645161290322
 0011 1111 with Q6.2 encoding is:  0000 1111 (numerator: 15) /  0011 1111 (denominator: 63) = 0.23809523809523808
 0011 1111 with Q7.1 encoding is:  0001 1111 (numerator: 31) /  0011 1111 (denominator: 63) = 0.49206349206349204
 0011 1111 with Q8 encoding is:  0011 1111 (numerator: 63) /  0000 0001 (denominator: 1) = 63.0
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I will point out that you've misunderstood Q numbers, and that the question is really about byte swapping, not Q number decoding.

Comment: " is really about byte swapping, not Q number decoding" I'm not so sure, OP would have to clarify. It seems like byte swapping was the means to an end (Q number decoding). I think I skimmed the Q number wiki too fast haha. Is the "m" component indicating a whole number, and the `n` indicating a fraction, where the first digit is halves, the second digit is quarters, the third digit is eights, etc.?

Answer (score -1):

This is an alternate approach to [my main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56223974/3141234). Read that one first.

This is a more protocol oriented approach. It encodes the numeratorBitWidth at the type level, so each instance only has to have enough memory to store `I`. Unfortunately, this requires a new struct definition for every type of Q encoded integer you might want (There's 16 variants just for 16 bit integers alone: `QEncoded1_15`, `QEncoded2_14`, ... `QEncoded15_1`, `QEncoded16_0`).

```
protocol QEncoded {
    associatedtype I: BinaryInteger

    var i: I { get set }
    static var numeratorBitWidth: Int { get } // "m"    
    static var denominatorBitWidth: Int { get }  // "n"

}

extension QEncoded {
    static var denominatorBitWidth: Int { return I().bitWidth - Self.numeratorBitWidth }

    static var qFormatDescription: String {
        let (m, n) = (self.numeratorBitWidth, self.denominatorBitWidth)
        return (n == 0) ?  "Q\(m)" : "Q\(m).\(n)"
    }

    var numerator: I {
        return i >> Self.denominatorBitWidth
    }

    var denominator: I {
        if Self.denominatorBitWidth == 0 { return 1 }
        let denominatorMask: I = (1 << I(Self.numeratorBitWidth)) - 1
        return i & denominatorMask
    }

    var ratio: Double { return Double(numerator) / Double(denominator) }
}
```

Example usage:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var binaryDescription: String {
        var binaryString = ""
        var internalNumber = self
        var counter = 0

        for _ in (1...self.bitWidth) {
            binaryString.insert(contentsOf: "\(internalNumber & 1)", at: binaryString.startIndex)
            internalNumber >>= 1
            counter += 1
            if counter % 4 == 0 {
                binaryString.insert(contentsOf: " ", at: binaryString.startIndex)
            }
        }

        return binaryString
    }
}

extension QEncoded {
    func test() {
        print("\(self.i.binaryDescription) with \(Self.qFormatDescription) encoding is: \(numerator.binaryDescription) (numerator: \(numerator)) / \(denominator.binaryDescription) (denominator: \(denominator)) = \(ratio)")
    }
}

struct QEncoded16_0: QEncoded {
    static let numeratorBitWidth = 16

    var i: UInt16
    init(bitPattern: I) { self.i = bitPattern }
}

struct QEncoded8_8: QEncoded {
    static let numeratorBitWidth = 8

    var i: UInt16
    init(bitPattern: I) { self.i = bitPattern }
}

struct QEncoded4_12: QEncoded {
    static let numeratorBitWidth = 4

    var i: UInt16
    init(bitPattern: I) { self.i = bitPattern }
}
```

Output:

```
 0011 1110 0000 1111 with Q16 encoding is:  0011 1110 0000 1111 (numerator: 15887) /  0000 0000 0000 0001 (denominator: 1) = 15887.0
 0011 1110 0000 1111 with Q8.8 encoding is:  0000 0000 0011 1110 (numerator: 62) /  0000 0000 0000 1111 (denominator: 15) = 4.133333333333334
 0011 1110 0000 1111 with Q4.12 encoding is:  0000 0000 0000 0011 (numerator: 3) /  0000 0000 0000 1111 (denominator: 15) = 0.2
```